# why can't I use reference type in the operator=?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to override `operator+` and `operator=` for my classes.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Integer {
public:
    int i;
    Integer operator+ (Integer&);
    Integer& operator= (Integer&);
};

Integer Integer::operator+(Integer& rhs) {
    Integer res;
    res.i = this->i + rhs.i;

    return res;
}

Integer& Integer::operator=(Integer& rhs) {

    this->i = rhs.i;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Integer i1, i2, i3;
    i1.i = 1, i2.i = 2;
    i3 = i1 + i2;
    cout << i3.i;
}
```

In visual studio 2017, the compiler complained that:

```
"E0349  no operator "=" matches these operands"
```

It seems that an `Integer` object doesn't match with `Integer&` in the `operator=` function. But it works for `operator+` function. It is very confusing.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `i1 + i2`  (logically) stores its result in a temporary.   `i3 = i1 + i2` needs to poass a reference to that temporary to `operator=()`.    References to temporaries must be `const`.   Your `operator=()` accepts a non-`const` reference, so is not a valid match.   `i1` and `i2` are named, so can be passed by non-`const` reference to `operator+()`.    It is  a good ideal to `const`-qualify references when the object past is not expected to be changed - this is true for both `operator=()` and `operator+()` functions.

Comment: Much wisdom on this and other operators can be found at [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3):

```
i3 = i1 + i2;
```

returns a temporary variable of type `Integer`.

Now, your `operator=` takes a `Integer&`. This is a reference to an `Integer`. The problem is that temporaries cannot bind to non-const references.

Just make sure you change to `const Integer&`. That is the default for all operator overloads anyway.

Comment: Not *all* operator overloads. The move assignment operator needs a non-const r-value reference.

Answer (score 2):

I'll break this down from the assignment statement.

```
i3 = i1 + i2;
```

The first thing that happens were is the addition expression gets evaluated.
That's this code snippet:

```
i1 + i2
```

You designed your operator overload to handle this expression.
Your custom addition operator overload returns a new `Integer` instance.
But the problem occurs when you try to assign this new instance to the parameter
in your assignment overload. Here's a snippet of that code.

```
Integer& Integer::operator=(Integer& rhs);
```

When you use a referenced parameter in a function declaration, the compiler checks to make sure that this value is not a temporary value, so that it will exist after the function is called. The compiler has determined (correctly) that the argument passed to this assignment statement is a temporary value. That is why it spits out an error when you try to do this.

The most logical why I see of making your code *make sense* is to implement the following:

```
Integer& Integer::operator=(const Integer& rhs) {
    this->i = rhs.i;
    return *this;
}
```

By adding the const-specifier, you tell the compiler that you're not relying on `rhs` to persist existence after calling the function. In that case, the value passed to the parameter may be a temporary value.

Comment: Your last sample for `Integer::operator=()` is a counter example? If so, please, mention it explicitly. It returns a reference to a local variable (`result`). This is [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) because once you have left the body of `operator=()` `result` goes out of scope and the returned reference becomes dangling.

Comment: @Scheff thanks for pointing this out. It looks like the code from the addition operator overload, I must've mixed them up some how without realizing it. I'm actually quite surprised it wasn't down voted. Fixing it now.